# Profiling help in asp.net

Tags: asp.net, .net-4.0, profiling, dottrace

I am building a site using WebFormsMvp and Entity Framework 4.

The site is a bit slow and when i profile in dotTrace these three methods take 75% of the time. (My first method takes about 3%)

1. **System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(SafeHandle,
   Int64, Boolean, Boolean)**
2. **Microsoft.Samples.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Pipe.PipeNative.ConnectNamedPipe(Int32,
   Overlapped)**
3. **Microsoft.Samples.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.Pipe.PipeNative.ReadFile(Int32,
   Byte[0..], UInt32, Byte[0..],
   UInt32)**

Anyone seen these three before that should shine some light on what this might be? I've tried to track them down but cannot find anything useful. I know this is a really hard question to answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are all routines that block threads. What you need to know is why you are calling for that I/O. There is a very simple way to find out - [stackshots](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/375913/what-can-i-use-to-profile-c-code-in-linux/378024#378024).
All you need is an IDE with a pause button.